# My Java apps appear enlarged and distorted when using JRE 9 and above

Tags: java, netbeans

I've many Java apps that I've created over the years.  I've been using Netbeans and JDK 1.8.xx.  I noticed that when I run my apps using JRE 9 and above that they appear slightly enlarged and somewhat distorted.  Including Jframes, Swing controls and drawing canvas.  Has anyone else experienced this problem, or have a solution?

TIA,

grecinos

Edit:
As per request, here are some screen captures:

[Before (with JRE 1.8X)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8uh0.jpg)

[After (with JRE 9+)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK6EE.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean the ui elements are visually distorted or the class/jar files are now larger?

Comment: The UI elements are visually distorted.  Specifically, I'd say they appear 20 to 25% larger.  The canvas that I use to draw shapes has the same problem.

Comment: @user2352682 Could you update your question to include a screen shot to show the distortion you are seeing? Also, which version of NetBeans are you using? NetBeans 8.2 and earlier do not support Java 9 or later.

Comment: I've updated the original post.  I'm using Netbeans 8.2.  As you can see the first image looks very sharp around the edges.  Whereas the second image appears jagged around the edges.

Comment: @user2352682 Your environment (NetBeans 8.2 with JRE 9) is not supported. If you want to use Java versions > 8 then [download and install NetBeans 9](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/nb90.html) which was released a couple of weeks ago. You can safely run NetBeans 9 concurrently with NetBeans 8.2 since the two releases do not impact each other at all. Actually, NB 8.2 is from Oracle, and NB 9 is from Apache. Update your question if you still have rendering problems when using NetBeans 9.

Comment: The only difference I’m able to see is the lack of antialiasing.  Consider including images showing the “distortion” of Swing components.

Comment: I recompiled my app with JDK 9.  (It took a while to find the proper syntax).  The result was the same.  Enlarged JFrame and drawing canvas.

Comment: VGR: antialiasing was enabled on both images.  The Swing components just look 20ish% larger.  Footnote:  when I save the images within my java app, they appear identical. Apparently it's just the UI that is being affected.

Comment: This is an update to my issue and a resolution that I just discovered.

Apparently, I'm having a scaling issue.  JRE 9 and 10 have different default scaling settings than it's predecessors.  The solution to this problem is to add the following argument when running the app, "-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0". 

This worked like a charm.  No changes to my code.  I'm a happy camper now.

Comment: @grecinos - Glad that you found a fix. im having the same problem where I cant fit my Swing app correctly in the screen. The margins are okay, but say you have a scroll pane with 4 text fields stacked one below the other (as per design), Im able to see only 2.5 the rest looks "cut" and im not able to scroll down as well (when the app is run). Where exactly did u add  "-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0" in your code to fix this?